# Evaluating beyond the range `PlotRange` can

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am having an equation which I want to plot.

```
eq = (Binomial[n, 2]*(3.97887*10^-10 Cos[200 k ArcSinh[50/k]])/
       Sqrt[1 + 2500/k^2] == -0.00003 // Rationalize) /. {n -> 
    10^logn, k -> 10^(-logk)}
```

This I solve using :

```
solk[logn_] := 
 logk /. NSolve[{(1.9894350000000002`*^-10 10^logn (-1 + 10^logn) Cos[
          200 (10^-logk)* ArcSinh[5*10^2 (10^logk)]])/
       Sqrt[1 + (25*10^2 10^(2 logk))] == -(3/10000), -65 < 
      logk < 0}, logk, Reals][[1]]
```

Then I plot using :

```
p1 = Plot[2.0*solk[logn], {logn, 0, 23}, 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 23}, {-60.0, -20}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, DotDashed, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 1000, 
  LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 16]}]
```

The problem is I need my `logk` to go down to values upto `-120` or so. Right now it's just in the range of `-65` to `0` and decreasing the lower value results in a null plot. I have identified that I get nothing on y-axis lower than about the value of `-6.2`. Below this value `Mathematica` doesn't show any plot data.

Can someone please tell me how do I make mathematica to evaluate and solve for the variable `logk` down till the value of `-120` and also plot it?

Please note that `logk` always appears as an exponent of `10` which certainly complicates things but I think it should be possible to for `Mathematica 11.0` to achieve this.

Plot for your kind reference : 
[image: Plot]

Comment: Note you have `-0.00003` in `eq` and `-(3/10 000)` in `solk` which looks like it should be `-(3/100 000)`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual advice is to adjust either the number of points being plotted by adding `PlotPoints -> n` to the `Plot[]` function, or to increase the recursion by adding `MaxRecursion -> m` to `Plot[]`. `n` might be in the range of 50 to 200, or `m` might be somewhere in the range of 5 to 10. One other issue I see is that you're forcing `solk[]` to only check for solutions where `-65 < logk < 0`. For some points, `NSolve` will not be able to find a solution due to this constraint.

Additionally, I get something obscene like 15 seconds to evaluate `solk[23]`. Things seem to get even dicier for something like `solk[2]`. Let's say you even just want to plot 20 values, you're looking at a minimum of 5 minutes of number crunching. I would recommend switching to `FindRoot`. For an equation like this, I don't see any advantage to using `NSolve`. With only 1 variable, `FindRoot` should be much faster.

```
solk2[logn_?NumericQ] := 
  logk /. FindRoot[
    (1.9894350000000002`*^-10 10^logn (-1 + 10^logn) 
    Cos[200 (10^-logk)*ArcSinh[5*10^2 (10^logk)]])/
    Sqrt[1 + (25*10^2 10^(2 logk))] == -(3/10000),
  {logk, -5, -120, 0}
]
list = Table[{logn, Quiet@solk2[logn]}, {logn, 1/1000, 23, 1/1000}];
ListLinePlot[
  list,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}
]
```

[image: Plot of the function evaluated using FindRoot.]

This only takes 28 seconds to evaluate 23,000 points on my computer, so I think you can get a lot more resolution using this method.

Run by itself, `sol2[]` will give warnings that you might not be using enough precision. I tried running it with `WorkingPrecision->100` and `1.9894350000000002'100*^-10` (where that apostrophe is actually a grave accent) instead of `1.9894350000000002*^-10`, but I got the same graph either way so I don't think it actually matters.

I also restricted the x-axis to be from 0 to 5 for the plotting, because that seemed to be the most interesting region. In fact, the 18,000 evaluations from 5 to 23 are probably wasted as it seems to just give the same value over and over. I don't know anything about the function you're plotting here, so you'll have to be the judge of whether it's correct or not.

Comment: That is a great help to me. A big thanks. Just a small clarification before I accept this as an answer. How can I know whether `MaxRecursion` will help me get to the required value of `logk` of `-120` or so (besides running it)? What to do if `MaxRecursion` can't get me there?

Comment: One more stupid question : `{logk, -5, -120, 0}` I don't understand what the zero means here. Can you please elucidate?

Comment: @Nitin Well, I don't know of anyway to know beforehand. `MaxRecursions` increases the number of times a region is recursively sampled by `Plot`. This can help if you have some very sharp peaks. If you want to get logk of -120, so far it doesn't look like that every happens, but maybe if you sample even more finely around 3... I'm not sure. It's buried in the "Details and Options" part of the `FindRoot` help page, but the format is `{x, xstart, xmin, xmax}`. So it starts with a guess of -5, and tries to find the zero of the function near there. It will give up if it goes < -120 or > 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. :)